# BlockBlobClient.UploadAsync fails when trying to modify the incoming WatchableReadStream object

Tags: azure, upload, blob

I hope you're having some advice because I'm pretty much out of options. What I'm trying to do:

- upload an image to a blobcontainer via the azure portal
- when doing that, the blobtrigger below fires.
- I want to resize the incoming image which is a `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.WatchableReadStream` object.
- I want to upload the result to a new blob container.

The issue is, when I am passing any other `Stream`, e.g. a `MemoryStream` than the unmodified `myBlob` object the `UploadAsync` method seems to silently fail and the `BlobTrigger` fires again, starting an endless loop. Writing to the current `myBlob` object also silently fails. Only thing which works is passing the `myBlob` object in `BlockBlobClient.UploadAsync` without ANY modification whatsoever, which is useless. I am doing a remote debugging session in Azure.

Also, when I try to feed a `MemoryStream` object to the `UploadAsync` method the same problem occurs. The method below is the blob trigger:

```
        public async Task UploadImage([BlobTrigger("mediafullsizecontainer/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            BlockBlobClient fullsizeBlobClient = _mediaFullsizeContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
            Response<BlobProperties> blobPropertiesResponse = await fullsizeBlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync(null, default);

            BlobProperties blobProperties = blobPropertiesResponse.Value;

            //Only process blobs when the correct metadata properties are set
            if (blobProperties.Metadata.Any(property => property.Key == "category" & property.Value != String.Empty))
            {
                string category = blobProperties.Metadata["category"];

                Stream s = await ResizeImage(myBlob);

                BlockBlobClient thumbnailBlobclient = _mediaThumbnailContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
                Response<BlobContentInfo> uploadResponse = await thumbnailBlobclient.UploadAsync(s, new BlobUploadOptions(), default);
                
                BlobContentInfo blobContentInfo = uploadResponse.Value;
            }
        }
```

The `ResizeImage` method uses the SixLabors.ImageSharp image processing library.

```
        public async Task<Stream> ResizeImage(Stream inputStream)
        {
            (Image image, IImageFormat imageFormat) imageWithFormat = await Image.LoadWithFormatAsync(inputStream);
            int height = imageWithFormat.image.Height;
            int width = imageWithFormat.image.Width;

            imageWithFormat.image.Mutate(operation => {
                operation.Resize(width / 4, height / 4);
            });

            MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            imageWithFormat.image.Save(outputStream, imageWithFormat.imageFormat);

            return outputStream;
        }
```

So when I do a mock change on the `myBlob` object like this, `myBlob.Write(buffer)` fails:

```
                byte[] buffer = new byte[myBlob.Length];
                myBlob.Read(buffer, 0, (int)myBlob.Length);

                myBlob.Position = 0;
                myBlob.Write(buffer);
```

When I copy the `myBlob` contents to a `MemoryStream` and pass the memoryStream to `UploadAsync`, `UploadAsync` fails:

```
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                myBlob.CopyTo(ms);
                 
                BlockBlobClient thumbnailBlobclient = _mediaThumbnailContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
                Response<BlobContentInfo> uploadResponse = await thumbnailBlobclient.UploadAsync(ms, new BlobUploadOptions(), default);
```

Only thing which works is passing the `myBlob` object without any modification to `UploadAsync` which is useless since I need to modify the incoming stream:

```
        public async Task UploadImage([BlobTrigger("mediafullsizecontainer/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            BlockBlobClient fullsizeBlobClient = _mediaFullsizeContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
            Response<BlobProperties> blobPropertiesResponse = await fullsizeBlobClient.GetPropertiesAsync(null, default);

            BlobProperties blobProperties = blobPropertiesResponse.Value;

            //Only process blobs when the correct metadata properties are set
            if (blobProperties.Metadata.Any(property => property.Key == "category" & property.Value != String.Empty))
            {
                string category = blobProperties.Metadata["category"];

                BlockBlobClient thumbnailBlobclient = _mediaThumbnailContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
                Response<BlobContentInfo> uploadResponse = await thumbnailBlobclient.UploadAsync(myBlob, new BlobUploadOptions(), default);
                
                BlobContentInfo blobContentInfo = uploadResponse.Value;
            }
        }
```

How can I pass a custom stream to the UploadAsync method? The documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.uploadasync?view=azure-dotnet says you just need a stream object - but this does not work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like I found the answer myself, I got rid of the dreaded `UploadAsync` method and did it like this by reading the `outputStream` of the resized image into a buffer then opening a `Stream` for writing to the `thumbnailBlobclient` object and passing the buffer to the stream object. It makes sense that trying to modify the incoming `myBlob` object which came with the trigger, fires the trigger again and creating a loop.

```
                Stream outputStream = await ResizeAndCropImage(myBlob);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[outputStream.Length];
                outputStream.Read(buffer);

                BlockBlobClient thumbnailBlobclient = _mediaThumbnailContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(name);
                Stream s = thumbnailBlobclient.OpenWrite(true, new BlockBlobOpenWriteOptions { HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpg" } }, default); //set http headers here as well?

                await s.WriteAsync(buffer);
                s.Close();
```

I will set the content type in a more generic way but this concept is working.